# Comparison between two dates

Tags: word-choice, grammar, dates

So, i have to translate a sentence that basically has this meaning:

> There cannot be a validity date before the revision date.

Or in broken english but making sense logically:

> Validity date must be > than revision date.

How would I form the sentence precisely and formally?  Perhaps the following:

> The validity date cannot be anterior to the revision date.

Is the sentence above correct?  How would you, as a native speaker, change it to make it sound more natural and formal?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are there any problems with _"The validity date cannot be before the revision date"_?

Comment: No problems, but it sounds weird to me (not a native speaker)

Comment: Do you mean *Validity date must be **>** revision date* or *Validity date must be **≥** revision date*? Your first sentence matches the latter; for the former, you'd need something like "The validity date must be after the revision date" or "There cannot be a validity date before *or on* the revision date."

Comment: Actually it's ≥, i think that i will use "The validity date cannot be before the revision date", as suggested by as4s4hetic

Comment: You can also say "The validity date must be later than the revision date"

Comment: We use *earlier* and *later* to indicate relative positions in time. *Before* and *after* are ambiguous regarding the dimension - it could be their position in a document, for example.

Comment: validity date cannot precede revision date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to say this is:

> The validity date cannot be before the revision date.

Answer (score 1):

Early and late are more specifically related to time than before and after and so I would say the validity date cannot be earlier than the revision date.